# Imploding in PHP vs imploding in MySQL - which uses less cpu?

Tags: php, mysql, database, casting, implode

Which of these options is more optimal?

**imploding in MySQL**

```
$rsFriends = $cnn->Execute('SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(id_friend) AS CHAR) AS friends 
                              FROM table_friend 
                             WHERE id_user = '.q($_SESSION['id_user']));
$friends = $rsFriends->fields['friends'];
echo $friends;
```

*vs.*

**imploding in PHP**

```
$rsFriends = $cnn->Execute('SELECT id_friend 
                              FROM table_friend 
                             WHERE id_user = '.q($_SESSION['id_user']));
while(!$rsFriends->EOF) {
    $friends[] = $rsFriends->fields['id_friend'];
    $rsFriends->MoveNext();
}
echo implode(',',$friends);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that "optimal" is contextual.  One person may need to reduce load on their app server, the other on their database server.

Comment: This would depend on your server configuration and the load and capacity of both your database and application servers. If you just want to see which is faster, test it!

Comment: @Renesis: True, but the database will scale large loads better than PHP/etc.  The question itself is relatively moot if PHP and the MySQL instance are on the same box.

Comment: Exactly, both run in the same server. I need to know which would take less work to the cpu.

Comment: @OMG Really? That's definitely an interesting question, I can't imagine PHP doing a worse job of receiving an `N * avg(idlength)` length string than `N` integers from the database.

Comment: @Renesis: The database is optimized for large datasets, and operations on them -- PHP is not.  Only the smallest resultsets will perform on par between PHP/etc and a database -- in which case, you have to question the requirement/algorithm...

Comment: Application ( PHP ) servers are cheaper then DB servers ( more RAM, RAID 5/10 volumes )... so do the implode in PHP where it's easier/cheaper to scale for.

Comment: @David: Riiight...  Don't solve the issue, just throw hardware at it.

Comment: @OMG Ponies The question was, "which is more optimal" and I answered that question from a cost/benefit ratio perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably know that the correct ("most optimal") choice is going to be a factor of many variables:

1. Your database and application hardware.
2. The size of your data
3. What load is already like on database and application servers.
4. Indexes and other things that may affect query execution plan on your dataset
5. How you *actually* want to use the data.
6. Network latency between app server and database server

But you can definitely analyze the program flow to help you arrive at an answer:

**Imploding in PHP**:

1. Execute a select query returning ALL friend IDs
2. Return every single ID to your application.
3. Build string in PHP as you read them from the result.

*Pros:*

- Flexibility in using raw IDs if you actually need them (meaning — if you go with creating the string in MySQL, but post-process it in PHP, the expensive post-process operations will likely negate benefit seen from bypassing PHP in the string-compilation stage)
- IDs could be (are?) returned to your application as numbers, not strings (`1234567890` is 10 bytes ASCII, 4 bytes as a 32-bit integer)

**Imploding in MySQL**:

1. Execute an aggregate query
2. Build a string as it aggregates the results
3. Return one single string to your application
4. Output that string

*Pros:*

- Might use less memory on the database server for large datasets
- Can't think of much else.  As soon as you need anything but a big concatenated string, this solution is definitely sub-optimal.

Comment: Flexibility does not mean performance.  Only with the smallest data sets, will PHP and the database perform equally.

Comment: @OMG - Updated to clarify meaning of including "flexibility"

Comment: Not even close...  Familiarity with code != application performance

Comment: Elaborate what?  You're making statements with no basis in fact, just your belief.  If you don't know, don't stick your neck out.

Comment: @OMG - "Elaborate" as in, I have no idea what specific part you have a problem with.  Is it not clear that I'm saying *if you start post-processing the string value in PHP, then the performance benefit from creating it in the database is completely negated*.  What do you mean by "Not even close... Familiarity with code != application performance"?

Comment: @OMG - BTW, I'd rather stick my neck out and help guide the asker to an answer that works for them than derive an isolated experiment that may point them in an entirely wrong direction for their real-world situation.

Comment: A con for group_concat in mysql is that by default it truncates the resulting string to 1024 characters, so if you have many columns you will run into this limitation.  This can be increased by changing the group_concat_max_len parameter but it's a consideration nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments, *optimal* is heavily depended on the context. With that said, my philosophy is: *if the database can do it, let it.*

Specifically for your case, if you don't analyze or manipulate the results - meaning this is strictly to join all records together for output - then I definitely vote database.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably most worth optimizing here is developer time and effort, for implementation and maintenance. The difference in CPU cycles (as a proportion of the total work being done) is most likely trivial. I suggest you do it whichever way you can write, test, and support most easily.